# Big O Notation for two code fragments

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've have two fragments of code and an explanation of what Big O category they fall into. However, try as I might, I can't tally the explanation with what I can come up either by looking at it or doing sample runs.

The first:

```
long count = 0;
long n = 1000;
long i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < i * i; j++) 
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++) 
                count++;
```

Sample runs of this consistently give me N^4, but the answer I've been given is "j can be as large as i^2, which could be as large as N^2. k can be as large as j, which is N^2. The running time is thus proportional to N^N^2^N^2, which is O(N^5)"

Second snippet:

```
long i, j, k;
long n = 1000;
long count = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 1; j < i * i; j++)
        if (j % i == 0)
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
                count++;
```

For this the notes say "The if statement is executed at most N3 times, by previous arguments, but it is true only O(N^2) times (because it is true exactly i times for each i). Thus the innermost loop is only executed O(N^2) times. Each time through, it takes O(j^2) = O(N^2) time, for a total of O(N^4)"

For this the notes seem to be accurate enough for the N^4 (although I keep getting a result of N^4 / 10). I don't follow the modulo calculation only being true i times for each i however, it seems to enter that loop a lot less.

So the question is can anyone clarify what I'm not understanding?

Comment: "I keep getting a result of `N^4 / 10`" - Big-O ignores multiplicative constants. And do you understand the first one, or you need an explanation for that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one:

```
sum from i = 0 to n-1 of
    sum from j = 0 to i*i-1 of
        sum from k = 0 to j-1 of
            1
```

We know the sum of 1 `m` times is equal to `m`, so we can reduce this to

```
sum from i = 0 to n-1 of
    sum from j = 0 to i*i-1 of
        j
```

We know the sum `1 + 2 + ... + m = m * (m + 1) / 2`, so we can reduce further:

```
sum from i = 1 to n-1 of
    (i * i - 1) * i * i / 2 = (1/2) * (i * i * i * i - i * i)
```

We can make this easier by taking the `(1/2)` outside the summation and then splitting up the `i * i * i * i` and `i * i` terms; however, the summations are still harder and less well-known than for `i` alone. It does turn out to be `Theta(n^5)` hence `O(n^5)`; to at least get an intuitive feeling for why this turns out, recognize that the difference `f(n+1) - f(n) = (1/2)(n^4-n^2)` which is on the order of `n^4`, so if `f` were a continuous function and this difference were the derivative, then the order of `f` would be one higher.

For the second case:

```
sum from i = 0 to n-1 of
    sum from j = 0 to i-1 of
        sum from k = 0 to i*j-1
            1
```

Note that `j` now assumes only `i` different values for the purposes of the innermost loop: `0, i, 2i, ..., (i-1)i`. The inner loop runs for i times as many iterations as the counter value for `j`. We do this multiplication shifting to avoid introducing a "step" notation so we can use our usual mathematical results.

```
sum from i = 0 to n-1 of
    sum from j = 0 to i-1 of
        i*j

sum from i = 0 to n-1 of
    i * (1/2) * i * (i - 1) = (1/2)(i * i * i - i)
```

Again, we can cheat or do the math or we can use our intuition again to (correctly) surmise this turns out to be `Theta(n^4)`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.
For my own interest, the way you've written the answer, is that for input into something that helps with this kind of reasoning?

Comment: @Saf It was an ad-hoc notation I just (possibly re-)invented to try to clarify the reasoning given absence of MathJax/LaTeX support on this SE site.